# Choose next date that isn't included in a set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a view that lists certain events taking place the next day

```
SELECT column1, column2...
FROM table1
WHERE date = CAST(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 DAY' AS DATE)
```

Nevertheless, I have a table of 'forbidden dates': I cannot use this specific set of dates, so, in case the next day is in that forbidden list, it must jump to the next one. Sort of like this:

```
SELECT column1, column2...
FROM table1
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 DAY' AS DATE) IN (SELECT DISTINCT date FROM forbidden_date)
        THEN CAST(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '2 DAY' AS DATE)
    ELSE 
        CAST(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 DAY' AS DATE)
    END = date
```

The problem is that "what if the second next day is also in the forbidden list? and so on and on?"

I actually could control all this from a script, but I'm just really curious if I could make it through with just a query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `generate_series` to return all dates from the next 365 days and chose the first one that *isn't* a forbidden date:

```
SELECT column1, column2...
FROM table1
WHERE date = (
    select min(d)
    from generate_series(current_date + 1, current_date + 365, '1 day') as dates(d)
    where d not in (select date from forbidden_dates))
```